# with css3, is it possible to make a tab-arrow pointing downward?

Tags: css

[image]
is it possible to create a triangle like what is pictured? even with the double border color?

(I achieve double border color in the box that this triangle will come out of by doing two divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating an empty div and giving it a width of 0, and placing a border of desired thickness to the opposite side you want the triangle to point.

You can then position it where you wish.

See http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/ for instructions.

Comment: For a more elegant solution, use the pseudo selectors :after and/or :before, as is explained here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/

Comment: if the world would fricken stop using IE, I would <3 you, Sir @ThomasM

Comment: We actually use ThomasM's method at work here. We tell people we have "functional support for IE" and "graceful degradation".

Comment: @TheLindyHop It's supported, starting in IE8, so it's definetely usable right now. If IE doesn't have the triangles, that's no big deal. Tell your client a site doesn't HAVE to look the same in every browser. If they really keep complaining, you could always use modernizr to check for the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

this method is using the one described by Jon Rohan (linked already by @RP.) to make triangles from border styles and a 0x0 sized block element (div's in this case)

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/PdwQs/)

I included additional divs for the inner white border, could be removed if you're trying to minimize the HTML elements

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            Howdy!
            <div id="tabarrowShadow"></div>
            <div id="tabarrow"></div>
            <div id="tabarrowInner"></div>
            <div id="tabarrowInner2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}
#div1 {border:solid 1px #ddd;padding:2px;background-color:#ebebeb;position:relative;}
#div2 {border:solid 1px #ddd;}
#div3 {border:solid 1px #f7f7f7;padding:25px;height:20px;}
#tabarrow {width:0;height:0;position:absolute;top:75px;left:20px;
    border-color:#ddd transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
}
#tabarrowInner {width:0;height:0;position:absolute;top:75px;left:22px;
    border-color:#f7f7f7 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:13px;
}
#tabarrowInner2 {width:0;height:0;position:absolute;top:74px;left:23px;
    border-color:#eee transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px;
}
#tabarrowShadow {width:1px;height:1px;box-shadow:0 0 10px 1px #000;position:absolute;top:86px;left:35px}
```